# PHP ftp_rawlist - options before directory

Tags: php, module, ftp

I'm looking for list of options, which can be used in PHP module FTP in methods ftp_nlist and ftp_rawlist before directory. There are some examples i found:

```
 // include hidden files
 ftp_rawlist($h, '-a /');

 // more complex - only names of files
 ftp_rawlist($h, '-1l /');
```

Maybe it is FTP server specific, but both work on Windows and Linux.
I there any specification with full list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Options are specific to LIST command of FTP server.

ListOptions available on Linux ProFTPd server.
http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/ListOptions.html